# What are the requirements for a tag to be synonym-ed?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

What I could find thus far about synonyms is only about the prerequisites for suggesting a synonym. I could not find a clear-cut answer for what I am facing. I am wondering if the following is a valid synonym request to make.

Consider a product, "Worklight".

- Its tag, `worklight`, is valid for all product versions up to v6.2
- Starting v6.3 the product has a new name and thus a new tag, `mobilefirst`

Questions:

1. Is this a case for a synonym? That is: `worklight` > `mobilefirst` (and for its child-tags as they are created in time once a question comes up, i.e. `worklight-adapters` > `mobilefirst-adapters`).
2. What exactly happens if a synonym such as the above is created?

   - Are new `worklight`-tagged questions auto-transform into `mobilefirst`-tagged questions?
   - Will searching for `worklight` or `mobilefirst` show up all questions from both tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case of [[Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordova/info)] on SO. It functions almost exactly as in your example. It was originally called Phonegap, but then they changed the name. [Cordova] was created, and [phonegap] either merged or synonymized with it.

So yes, that's basically how tag synonyms work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "how tag synonyms" works? do both my questions depict how it works? What does "merged" mean? Sorry for being dense, I'd just like the answer in clearer wording.